# This expression was expected to have type float but here has type 'a * 'b

Tags: f#, floating-point, int

I'm trying a simple F# script that will find pythagoras.

Here's the code:

```
open System

let FindHypotenuse a b =
    Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a, 2.0) + Math.Pow(b, 2.0))

FindHypotenuse(2.0, 3.0)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would code it: `let hypotenuse a b = sqrt (a * a + b * b) : float` which is more readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've defined the function to take two curried arguments, but then called it with a tuple.  Either call it as

```
FindHypotenuse 2.0 3.0  // no commas
```

or redefine it to take a tuple

```
let FindHypotenuse(a,b) = ...
```

Note that "`'a * 'b`" is the name of a tuple type.  See also:

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/03/f-function-types-fun-with-tuples-and-currying/